# How to orient a layer to connect 2 points AND facing the camera

Tags: 3d, three.js, rotation, orientation

here is my question, which I hope will be in general interest:

If you have got 2 Points in 3D space and want a (flat) Layer to connect those, you can quite easily use a function similar to "lookAt" to orient the layer pointing with its x-axis from one point to the other.
But how can you at the same time make sure the layer is rotated in the way so that the layer is facing the camera (the maximum amount possible, of course it cant be orthogonal to the camera)?

I have tried this code on the orientation property of an After Effects Layer. I post this because I was asked to do. The question is more about how to generally achieve my desired result with code.

```
startLayer = thisComp.layer("A");
start = startLayer.toWorld(startLayer.anchorPoint);
endLayer = thisComp.layer("B");
end = endLayer.toWorld(endLayer.anchorPoint);

vec = end - position;
l = length(start,[end[0],start[1],end[2]]);
y = -radiansToDegrees(Math.atan2(vec[2],vec[0]));
z = radiansToDegrees(Math.atan2(vec[1],l)) ;
[0,y,z];
```

result
[image: result]

layer has visibly disapeared
[image: layer has visibly disapeared]

Comment: You may also want to ask this question here: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Could you post the code you've tried and a picture with the desired result? Please, read about [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Hi prisoner I thought my question is about how to generally achieve this with code. To post my code could be just more confusing. It is an expression on the orientation property inside After Effects.

Comment: @ayma why not to use `THREE.ConeGeometry()` or `THREE.CylinderGeometry()` for that purpose?